# How can I assign a shared foreign key to all records inserted using the Data Load Wizard?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an ApEx application which, amongst other purposes, has a requirement to upload billing data provided by telecommunications providers. The data is being provided as a CSV file.

We have two tables. The first table, `phone_invoice`, contains per-invoice metadata such as billing dates and provider name. The second table, `phone_invoice_detail` is based largely on call logs.

`phone_invoice_detail` has a foreign key, `invoice_id`, which keys into `phone_invoice(id)`. This creates a stock-standard master-detail relationship.

We have used the ApEx Data Load Wizard to set up the import capability for our users. But I need to assign the `invoice_id` to each imported row.

Currently, I have a Phone Invoice page. Users click a button, "Import Data for Invoice", which branches to the Data Load Wizard and sets a page item, `P1000_INVOICE_ID` with the value of that invoice ID -- `P999_ID`.

When the user begins the process, the CSV data supplied has all the fields *except* for an invoice ID. What I want is for that column in the underlying table -- `invoice_id` -- to be set to to the value of `P1000_INVOICE_ID`.

My current focus is on using the Transformation Rules. This has been tremendously frustrating because the documentation tells you nothing about them and there are no examples.

Permutations I have tried:

```
-- PL/SQL Expression:
:INVOICE_ID := :P1000_INVOICE_ID
:INVOICE_ID := :P999_ID
SELECT :P1000_INVOICE_ID INTO :INVOICE_ID FROM DUAL
SELECT :P999_ID INTO :INVOICE_ID FROM DUAL

-- Replace:
-- Expression 1           Expression 2
:P1001_INVOICE_ID         :INVOICE_ID
:P999_INVOICE_ID          :INVOICE_ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, APEX creates 4 pages for import. And it use apex collection named `LOAD_CONTENT` to store imported data. So, you can change this collection before it will be loaded into the table.

Go to the page named 'Data Validation' (this page have report `Data Validation`), and add page process, with next parameters:

Type:   **PL/SQL anonymous block**

Process Point: **On Load - Before Header**

**Source**:

```
declare 
  -- Local variables here
  i integer;
begin
  for i in (
    select t.seq_id
     from apex_collections t
     where t.collection_name = 'LOAD_CONTENT'
  ) loop
    apex_collection.update_member_attribute(
      p_collection_name => 'LOAD_CONTENT',
      p_seq => i.seq_id,
      p_attr_number => 3, -- here number of your column you want update
      p_attr_value => :P1000_INVOICE_ID -- value 
    );      
  end loop;  
end;
```

But change in this process number of your column.
I've tried this example in my APEX version 4.1 - it works fine.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll have a look at this on Monday.

Comment: It works, but as sometimes happens, the requirements have changed.